# rank gets affected by groupby, why

Tags: sql-server

I've recently seen a query like below (the rank, dense_rank, with group by clause). I found the group by clause makes the rank behaves like dense rank, and could not find microsoft documentation about it.

```
with FactTransactionHistory as
(
select 2 as ProductKey,'abc1' as trx
union
select 3 as ProductKey,'abc1' as trx
union
select 4 as ProductKey,'abc' as trx
union
select 4 as ProductKey,'abc2' as trx
union
select 4 as ProductKey,'abc3' as trx
union
select 5 as ProductKey,'abc' as trx
)
select ProductKey, DENSE_RANK() over(order by ProductKey) rowNumDense, RANK() over(order by ProductKey) rowNum
/*, count(*) recordCount*/
from FactTransactionHistory
group by ProductKey
```

My understanding is if the `over clause` has `partition by`, it will be ordered within the partition, hence the rank value is determined within the partition.
But this query has no `partitition by`, so the `order by` is on the whole dataset, and I could not explain about the rank function, why it is behaving like dense_rank.
Can you please help on explaining why?

**Note**: if I remove the `group by` clause, the rank and dense_rank has shown different value as the documentation stated.

[image: query results]

Comment: Where is `RANK` behaving like `DENSE_RANK`? In the only data set they would differ, `RANK` (which you have confusingly aliased `rowNum`) is giving a different result to `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: Both window functions operate on a dataset obtained *after* grouping has been applied. So, when `GROUP BY` clause is present, 'whole dataset' is a dataset with distinct ProductKey values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found the `group by` clause makes `rank` behave like `dense rank`.

These two ranking functions only differ on how they handle ties. Here, you are ordering the `over()` clause of the window function with the same column that is used in the `group by` - that is `ProductKey`. By nature, aggregation guarantees no duplicates on the product key, so both functions give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

> But this query has no `partition by`, so the `order by` is on the whole dataset

This is the place where your expectation goes wrong. To quote [the docs on the `OVER` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> If `PARTITION BY` is not specified, the function treats all rows of **the query result set** as a single group.

My emphasis. It's the *result set* rows, not the *source rows*, that make up the single partition here.